# How to make Logwatch track git commits

Tags: php, git, logwatch

I have a webserver with a git repo containing a website. I have made a CMS using PHP where PHP automatically commits to git when files are changed. I would like to track these commits (preferably in a form close to `git log --name-status` to show added/deleted files) using Logwatch. I have read about creating custom Logwatch services, but Logwatch is all really new to me and that didn't really get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Instead of the PHP code below, if you wanted to track all git commits (and not only those committed using PHP), it should be possible to set up a post-commit hook with similar output.

---

Just after writing the question I came across [this really simple guide](http://alphahydrae.com/2012/08/logwatch-how-to-add-a-service/). Based on that, here's what I did:

### Create log directory and set permissions

I haven't tested this without setting permissions, but I assume it's needed.

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/gitweb
sudo chown: www-data /var/log/gitweb
```

### PHP git log function

This line of code is run whenever I run `git commit` in the php code. Newlines are replaced with a custom string so that each commit is on its own line (as far as I know, Logwatch can only operate on a line-by-line basis). This will be replaced back with newlines when parsing with Logwatch.

```php
shell_exec('(git log -1 --date=iso --name-status | awk 1 ORS="[NEWLINE_HERE]" ; echo) >> /var/log/gitweb/gitweb.log');
```

### Logwatch log file group

```
# /etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/gitweb.conf

LogFile = gitweb/*.log
Archive = gitweb/*.gz
*ExpandRepeats
```

Not really sure what *ExpandRepeats does, but it was in the guide I linked to.

### Logwatch service

```
# /etc/logwatch/conf/services/gitweb.conf

Title = "Git commits"
LogFile = gitweb
```

### Logwatch parser

This does two things:

- Time filtering (it only prints lines/commits with the correct date)
- Convert custrom string back to newlines (see the PHP code above)

I know absolutely zero perl (I looked at other Logwatch scripts for help), so I apologize if this is a sacrilege against all things perl-y.

```perl
use Logwatch ':dates';

my $filter = TimeFilter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

while (defined(my $ThisLine = <STDIN>)) {
   if ($ThisLine =~ /$filter/) {
      $ThisLine =~ s/\[NEWLINE_HERE\]/\n/g;
      print $ThisLine;
   }
}

exit(0);
```

### Set up log rotation

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/gitweb

/var/log/gitweb/*log {

    daily

    # keep 10 old logs
    rotate 10

    # don't do anything if the log is missing
    missingok

    # don't do anything if the log is empty
    notifempty

    # zip the archived logs
    compress
}
```